# Bitwise Absolute Value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

If I wanted to find the absolute value of a 24-bit two's complement integer, would it be best to mask the integer, and if needed negate the original number?

To better illustrate what I mean:

```
public static int bitwiseAbsoluteValue(int n) {
      if (n == 0x800000) {
           return 0x000000;
      } else {
           if ((n & 0x800000) == 0x800000) {
                 return (~n + 1) & 0x7FFFFF;
           } else {
                 return n;
           }
      }
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: Hmm, what is wrong with `Math.abs(n)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd also need to mask the first return value:

```
return (~num + 1) & 0x7FFFFF;
```

And you'd need to work out what you want to do if the the value passed in is `0x800000`.  The current function would return `0`, which is obviously not correct.

Comment: I'm assuming that n is a 32-bit int that you're using to store your 24-bit value.  If you store, say, `-4` as `0x00FFFFFC`, then without the mask you'll end up with 0xFF000004.  Just depends on how you handle the high bits that you're not using elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Ok I modified the original code above so that it reflects your suggestion and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @oexcz, your code says that 0x800000 is positive. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, that should return 0 I guess.

Comment: Hmmm when I pass in 0x800000 I just get 0x800000 back. When would it throw an exception?

Comment: I'm suggesting that maybe you should add code to the function to throw an overflow exception instead of just `return 0x800000;`.  You need some way to tell code that's calling your function that there's an invalid result.  Either that or just silently overflow to `0` and document the behaviour.

Comment: If you're happy to just silently overflow to `0`, then you don't need the extra check. The `(~num + 1) & 0x7FFFFF` line will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way it can be done without `Math.abs(n)` would be something like this:

```
public static int findAbs(int n){
  if(n<0){return -1*n;}
  return n;
}
```

Comment: This will not fulfilled OP's requirement for 24-bit, as default int in Java is 32 bit.

Comment: This would probably be slower than bit-wise ops.

Comment: I was mainly operating off of OP's comment of
_"I'm curious to know how it's done without using any built in functions."_

Answer (score 0):

You could just subtract it from 0x1000000 (which is 1<<24) if bit 23 is set.

Answer (score 0):

That would work. Though you can only store up to +127, and down to negative -128. So the negation of -128, plus 1 would be a negative number. There's not much that can be done about that if the returned number is also supposed to be 24-bits.

Sorry, replace the +127 and -128 with the largest positive and negative numbers that can be stored with 24-bits. They're meant to illustrate the point that in 2's complement you can store negative number that has an absolute value 1 larger than the biggest positive number you can store. So you need to figure out how you want to deal with it if the number you're given is the biggest negative number (0x80000000 in 2's complement).

Comment: what you describe is an 8-bit number. a 24-bit signed integer can store -2^23 to 2^23-1. 2^23 is 8,388,608.

Comment: btw, `~num` is not negation, it's bit complement. You might want to look up what two's complement means.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use 8-bit numbers as an example of how 2's complement numbers can store 1 more negative number than positive numbers. And I do know what 2's complement is, but I see how this makes it look like I don't.

Comment: Oh yeah. It can also be called bitwise negation.

Answer (score 0):

Shift it left 8 bits then shift right 8 bits again (arithmetic shift, not logical shift). That will propagate the sign bit correctlyif there is one.